# Right way to convert a model to entity in Flutter, MVVM architecture?

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, solid-principles, clean-architecture

I'm a beginner in MVVM architecture and I'm stuck on an issue in a product app.

The issue: **Mapping a Model to an Entity**

Let me explain my code structure;

> Domain > Respository > order_repo.dart

This `order_repo.dart` is an abstract class `OrderRepo` that declares a function `getOrders` that returns `OrderEntity`.

---

> Data > Repo Implementation > order_repo_impl.dart

The `order_repo_impl.dart` contains a class `OrderRepoImpl` that defines the function `getOrders` that returns `OrderModel` that extends `OrderEntity`.

---

> Domain > Usecase > order_usecase.dart

The `order_usecase.dart` contains a class that uses `OrderUsecase` that uses an instance of `OrderRepo` to `call` `getOrders`. Both the `getOrders` and `call` functions return `OrderEntity`.

---

The problem is that when I call the usecase, I expect it to return `OrderEnity` but the `runtimeType` is OrderModel. I tried to parse it as `OrderModel` but I could not do that because I get this warning, `Unnecessary Cast`, because at compile time the compiler is also expecting `OrderEntity`.

One solution I found is to define a `Translator`, that would convert `OrderModel` to `OrderEntity` inside `usecase`, but I'm confused regarding the right place for its definition, because I cannot use `OrderModel` inside the `Domain` layer as per `Clean Architecutre` to keep `Domain` independent of other layers and if I define the `Tanslator` inside `Data` layer, I still cannot call it in the `usecase`, because of the same reason.

Comment: Why you need to change runtimeType. Isn't that a point in polymorphism that you can abstract your entity behind model interface?

Comment: The problem is that the runtimeType is different from the expected type.

Comment: Why is it not ok?
Your code still treats OrderEntity as OrderModel and doesn't have access to db-specific methods. That's the point of interfaces.

Comment: `OrderEntity` contains a property of type `List<OrderProductEntity>`, and when I try to update this list with new products, it gives this error, `OrderLineEntity is not a subtype of OrderLineModel`. This error is raised because the `OrderEntity` instance inside the controller has now the `runtimType` of `OrderEntityModel`.

Answer (score 3):

**It is bad practice**

`The order_repo_impl.dart contains a class OrderRepoImpl that defines the function getOrders that returns OrderModel that extends OrderEntity.`

1. Not always model can extend entity f.e. (Code-Generated Model)
2. The domain layer should not know about implementation and about the data layer, because Implementation can change but Business logic will not as long as there is no changes in business logic.

`I found is to define a Translator that would convert OrderModel to OrderEntity inside usecase`

**It is good practice**

It is good practice to convert it inside implementation of repository. Because, repository is kind of binding between domain and data layers,

Or even, You can create converter class that translate entity to model and vice verca and the instance of the class will be to the constructor of repository implementation.

Why it is better to follow these advices.

1. Implementation quite often can change but abstraction rarely changes.
2. Easy to switch from one implementation to another one.
3. You follow SOLID principles

P.s. I hope I could answer to your question. Whether you have feel free to ask it on comments